# How do I get my DNN Azure website to use Redis Cache?

Tags: dotnetnuke, azure-web-app-service, dotnetnuke-7, azure-redis-cache

I've successfully deployed my DNN website to azure, using azure sql database, via Webmatrix3.

I've created an azure redis cache to try and speed up performance.

I've searched and searched but haven't found documentation on how to hook the website up to use the cache. Do I have to integrate it somehow in WebMatrix and republish?

Found this for integrating ASP.NET app via Visual Studio: [MSFT Documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-web-app-howto/#configure-the-application-to-use-redis-cache)

```
<appSettings>
add key="CacheConnection" value="MyCache.redis.cache.windows.net,abortConnect=false,ssl=true,password=..."/
</appSettings>
```

Can I use the same appSettings line that I find in my DNN web.config, placing my newly created azure redis cache values for "key" and "value"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [DNN Redis Caching provider](https://github.com/davidjrh/dnn.rediscachingprovider) you will need to use.  I have not set it up on Azure, but it works great locally and should be easy enough to setup on Azure.